# Placeholder of Camel from tag is not getting updated with new values

Tags: spring, apache-camel, dsl

I have my publicAddress property defined in Spring XML and using it in Java DSL(Route builders). Value of 'publicAddress' comes from Web GUI.

```
<util:properties id="service-properties">
    <prop key="publicAddress"></prop></util:properties>
```

I was previously using Camel 2.10 and have switched to 2.15.

Following code is used to create Route builders which has different public addresses. With this code in place, if I create second Route builder, value of 'publicAddress' does not gets updated. RouteBuilder gets created with old value of 'publicAddress'

```
from(abcd+ ":"+ serviceName+ "://{{publicAddress}}?loggingEnabled= {{loggingEnabled}}").routeId(xyz + serviceName + "Route");
```

I tried using service-properties:{{publicAddress}} but that gave me null value.
Any idea which placeholder I need to use to resolve this issue ?

Comment: is this the same issue discussed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9124?